# Video Transmission in NS-3

Tags: video-streaming, simulation, ns-3

I am trying to do a simulation for my masters and I need to simulate video transmission and streaming. I already have the video trace files but I can't figure out how to code them into the NS-3 script. I started just by doing a simple topology just simulating a simple Wifi (based on the tutorial) but I haven't found where to read and send the fail. Any help?

Comment: Did you actually mean  "where to read and send the fail"?  I don't even know what that means.

Comment: Can you please explain what do you mean by ""where to read and send the fail"?

Comment: Check udp-trace-client.cc in examples of NS-3. May be that will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use simulation with UDP with OnOffApplication datarate more than 500 kbps as an video stream datarate.
Or you can send real traffic to ns3 simulation using some sofware like VLC